# .net mvc template for events/arrangements with responsive design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to find a good template for a event that my company is going to arrange.

The template I'm looking for have to be:

- responsive design (focusing on mobile  (iOS, Android and WP8)
- calendar showing events, (showing only events in the future)
- login
- maps

Isn't there any template for events out there?

I've tried:

- ASP.NET MVC 4 Bootstrap Layout template
- HTML5 MVC4 Razor Responsive web template

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://wrapbootstrap.com/

I've already tried some templates there and they are very easy to implement. Maybe you'll need a combination of multiple templates.